# Haskell Parser Seperator

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am using Parsec to write a parser for a logfile. Every line of that logfile follows a common structure `A:B:C:D` with the components A, B, C and D following simple rules. I've already written parsers for each of the components and I would like to combine them into a single parser. My current approach works, but I feel there has to be a nicer solution. One immediate drawback is that it would not scale very well for logfiles with more than 4 components.

```
parser :: (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser c -> Parser d -> Parser e
parser f pa pb pc pd = f <$> pa <* (char ':') <*> pb <* (char ':') <*> pc <* (char ':') <*> pd
```

I searched for a fitting parser combinator, but the only combinator coming close is `sepBy`, which does not work for this use case. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best option is to introduce your own operator, e.g.:

```
infixl 4 <:>
p <:> q = p <* char ':' <*> q
```

Then you don't need to define a separate `parse` function, it is just as easy to just write the implementation:

```
myParser = f <$> pa <:> pb <:> pc <:> pd
```

This is easily extended:

```
myParser2 = g <$> pa <:> pb <:> pc <:> pd <:> pe
```

Comment: That is a good idea! Unfortunately, the way I defined `<:>` it appears to be bonding stronger than `<$>`, meaning I have to put parentheses around `(f <$> pa)`. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: @Lando-L I added a fixity declaration to my answer, that should make it work properly. I made it the same fixity as `<*>`, which I looked up using `:info (<*>)` in GHCi.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't know about the concept of fixity. I'll have a proper look at it.